# Send photo using telegram.bot

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I want to create a Robot in Telegram. After searching, I found telegram.bot in a Nuget Package.

But I'm having trouble sending a photo. The function definition is like

```
Bot.SendPhoto(int channelId, string photo, string caption)
```

But I don't know what is expected in the `string photo` parameter. Should I convert my image to a base64 string, or pass an image path, or ...?

My code currently looks like this

```
var Bot = new Telegram.Bot.Api("API KEY");
var b = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData(a.DefaultImage());
System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(new System.IO.MemoryStream(b));
var z = bmp.GetThumbnailImage(200, (200 * bmp.Height) / bmp.Width, 
   new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(
      delegate { return true; }), IntPtr.Zero);
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
z.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
var x = new Telegram.Bot.Types.FileToSend() 
{ 
    Filename = a.DefaultImage().Split('/').LastOrDefault(), Content = ms 
};

var t = Bot.SendPhoto("@Chanel", x, a.Title);
```

But this is causing an exception

> Telegram.Bot.Types.ApiRequestException: [Error]: Bad Request: File to
>   send must be non-empty

Comment: There is no `Tele Bot` package in NuGet repository. What is actual name of package that you use? It is `TeleBotDotNet` or `telegram.bot`?

Comment: What kind of problem do you have? Do you obtain an exception or what else?

Comment: i not undrestand put to **String Photo** Attribute on this Function

Comment: A guess: The stream needs to have it's `Position` reset to the beginning. Use `ms.Position=0` before passing it to `SendPhoto`. If that doesn't work. Have you debugged and checked that the `MemoryStream` holds image data?

Answer (score 5):

According to the [source code method documentation](https://github.com/MrRoundRobin/telegram.bot/blob/master/Telegram.Bot/Api.cs) you should pass "a file_id as String to resend a photo that is already on the Telegram servers, or upload a new photo using multipart/form-data". My guess is that the parameter comment is generic and that this overload only accepts the file_id of an existing file on the server.

```
/// <summary>
/// Use this method to send photos. On success, the sent Message is returned.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="chatId">Unique identifier for the target chat</param>
/// <param name="photo">Photo to send. You can either pass a file_id as String to resend a photo that is already on the Telegram servers, or upload a new photo using multipart/form-data.</param>
/// <param name="caption">Optional. Photo caption (may also be used when resending photos by file_id).</param>
/// <param name="replyToMessageId">Optional. If the message is a reply, ID of the original message</param>
/// <param name="replyMarkup">Optional. Additional interface options. A JSON-serialized object for a custom reply keyboard, instructions to hide keyboard or to force a reply from the user.</param>
/// <returns>On success, the sent Message is returned.</returns>
public async Task<Message> SendPhoto(int chatId, string photo, string caption = "", int replyToMessageId = 0, ReplyMarkup replyMarkup = null)
```

The overload

```
public async Task<Message> SendPhoto(int chatId, FileToSend photo, 
    string caption = "", int replyToMessageId = 0,
    ReplyMarkup replyMarkup = null)
```

accepts a `FileToSend` that holds a file name and stream. Use that second overload for uploading new photos.

Disclaimer: I haven't used the API, so these are purely deductions from checking the source code.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try like this =>

```
Bot.SendPhotoAsync(Chatid ,  new FileToSend(FileName,Streaminput),Caption);
```

This api is default api for the send photo with caption on telegram bot.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same exception when I tried to send a photo from a stream. And yes, the problem was that Position was not on 0. So the next line has solved my problem.

```
stream.Position = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try like this if you need then.

```
Bot.SendPhoto(int channelId,photo : "http://abc.jpeg",caption:"hii");
```

on telegram bot you are send image, videos like 2 way. first is you can send like convert your image in to stream and then send on and 2nd is i am give like just pass photo:"here give url as string" then telegram bot server automatically download this image from url.